# Data set in observable not updating in template

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I'm trying to learn Angular 2 and am rebuilding an Angular 1 app I've made with Angular 2 using the Angular CLI. I've setup a HTTP GET request, which fires successfully, and setup a subscriber to interpret the result, and console logging in the subscriber function shows the data I expect. However, no data is being updated on the template.

I tried setting the data to an initial value, to a value in the ngOnInit, and in the subscriber function, and the initial and ngOnInit update the template accordingly. For the life of me, I can't figure out why the template won't update on the subscribe.

```
events: any[] = ['asdf'];

constructor(private http: Http) {
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.events = ['house'];
    this.getEvents().subscribe(this.processEvents);
}

getEvents(): Observable<Event[]> {
    let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    params.set('types', this.filters.types.join(','));
    params.set('dates', this.filters.dates.join(','));
    return this.http
        .get('//api.dexcon.local/getEvents.php', { search: params })
        .map((response: Response) => {
            return response.json().events;
        });
}

processEvents(data: Event[]) {
    this.events = ['car','bike'];
    console.log(this.events);
}
```

The data is being displayed via an ngFor, but car and bike never show. Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have gone wrong with not respecting the `this` context of TypeScript, if you do stuff like this:

```
 .subscribe(this.processEvents);
```

the context get lost onto the `processEvents` function.

You have to either bind it:

```
 .subscribe(this.processEvents.bind(this));
```

Use an anonymous function:

```
 .subscribe((data: Events) => {this.processEvents(data)});
```

Or set your method to a class property:

```
processEvents: Function = (data: Event[]) => {
    this.events = ['car','bike'];
    console.log(this.events);
}
```

Pick your favourite, but I like the last option, because when you use `eventListeners` you can easily detach them with this method.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I understand better now. I put it in a different function to avoid replicating the code, so I may go for the second option you put, but when I do this in general, I'll probably opt for the third. Thank you.

Comment: I face the very same issue, ie, seeing the console log display the updating progress, but nothing being updated in the template, until the completion. Do you think I could be faced with a similar this miss use ? https://stackoverflow.com/q/65060800/958373

Answer (score 2):

Not really sure with what's going on with that `processEvents`. If you want to subscribe to your response just do:

```
this.getEvents()
  .subscribe(data => {
     this.events = data;
});
```

Comment: Or you can do `this.getEvents().subscribe(data =>  { this.processEvents(data) });` , which isn't exactly 100% efficient, but...

Comment: Well, I figured since there's more going on in `processEvents`, I should create a function for it. But whether a lambda function or class method, does it matter?

Comment: No, I totally agree with you. Don't create a method/function if you don't need to. I just assumed that there is something else that's going one with the `processEvents` function, since it does set an array of `events` and can possibly be required. That's why I like promises, because you can just `.then` everything...